# How to create ToString() method for table in datacontext

Tags: vb.net

I have a table object in a datacontext,  I've created an object from it, and a List(Of T) of those objects.

However, when watching in the debugger, it doesn't display a nice summary of the record. The debugger uses an object's ToString() method to display this summary.

So, how do I create a ToString() function for an object defined in the datacontext.  Normally if you define a class, you use:

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() as String
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom class that inherits from table and override the tostring method.